# Flask SQLAlchemy:count function not aggregating as expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query that looks like this:

```
actests_daily = (
            db.session.query(
                func.count(AcTests.problem_solving_test_id),
                func.count(AcTests.personality_test_id),
                func.count(AcTests.spatial_ability_test_id),
                func.date(AcTests.last_test_submit_time),
            )
            .filter(AcUsers.last_test_submit_time != None)
            .group_by(
                AcTests.problem_solving_test_id,
                AcTests.personality_test_id,
                AcTests.spatial_ability_test_id,
                func.date(AcTests.last_test_submit_time),
            )
            .all()
        )
```

I am trying to know how many users have data in the fields above
the result was:

```
[(1, 0, 1, datetime.date(2022, 8, 1)), (0, 0, 1, datetime.date(2022, 8, 1))]
```

I was expecting it to aggregate to something like:

```
[(1, 0, 2, datetime.date(2022, 8, 1))]
```

It is met to aggregate but it did not. Please what did I do wrong in the query. Thank you in advance

Comment: Presumably there is more than one distinct value for one of the columns in the group by clause.

Comment: Yes, any user can take any of the test, so am trying to find the number of user that took each of the test

Comment: Then I think you would want the equivalent of `select user_id, count(test1), count(test2), count(test3) from tbl group by user_id` .

Comment: So I had to count the individual test separately and group them by the dates. Because the tests had different columns in the database. So in short, my query was very wrong this was the better query for each individual test. e.g.  
        test_one = (
            db.session.query(
                func.count(Tests_one.id),
                func.date(Tests_one.submit_time),
            )
            .group_by(
                func.date(Tests_one.submit_time),
            )
            .all()
        )